# Should I upgrade a weapon/armour before prestigeing it?

Tags: trimps

When I can 'prestige' a weapon, it says:

"This will destroy your existing [pants] and greatly increase the cost of future upgrades"

Does this mean I should upgrade them as much as possible beforehand, or do the upgrades not carry over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you prestige, you will lose all the upgrades.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: What is the point of prestiging an item, then? Does it mean that future upgrades become more potent?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Yes, you get quite a bit more effect from the prestiged equipment.